# Change Number formatting in a Data Frame

Tags: r

How do you change the number formats in a data frame. As you can see for Number of policies up to Median the value does not look good. And the %Missing up to % Negative it should be a percentage. Below are my codes.

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(Count, Min, Max, Mean, Median, Percmissing, PercZero, Percone, Percnegative))
rownames(df) = c("Number of policies", "Min", "Max", "Mean", "Median", "% Missing", "% Zero", "% One", "% Negative") 
colnames(df)= c("Value")
```

And this is the output.

```
> df
                           Value
Number of policies  1.390400e+04
Min                -2.490000e+05
Max                 5.500000e+08
Mean                4.957919e+07
Median              2.200000e+07
% Missing           4.568470e-01
% Zero              4.602992e-03
% One               3.610472e-02
% Negative          1.438435e-04
```

I used the percent function to output a percentage value but it does not output it on the data frame. This is my code to get the percentage.

```
library(formattable)
#Percentage of missing
missing = Countmissing / countdataV
Percmissing <- percent(missing)

> Percmissing
    [1] 45.68%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dataframe `df` you already have correct percentage data, as you can read on wikipedia: [In mathematics, a percentage is a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) You don't need mandatorily the representation that you are looking for. So what you are trying to do is just a visualization using "%" symbol, the function `percent` just modify the representation of the number.

Otherwise, if you want to store that visualization in your dataframe try this code:

```
library("formattable")
df[c(6:9),]<-as.character(percent(df[c(6:9),]))
df
                      Value
Number of policies    13904
Min                 -249000
Max                 5.5e+08
Mean               49579190
Median              2.2e+07
% Missing            45.68%
% Zero                0.46%
% One                 3.61%
% Negative            0.01%
```

In this example you have your desired visualization but the class of the percentage values is moved to character (and this is not very positive from an analytics point of view).

Comment: Thanks this works. However I can't vote your answer because I'm still new and had 7 reputations.

Comment: You can accept the answer with a click on the check mark on the left of the answer. You don't have to up vote the answer too.

Comment: Hi Just a follow up question, how can I make a better number visualization on the Max and Median?

Comment: If you want prevent scientific notation use "options(scipen=999)" in top of your code